# How can I access phpMyAdmin through terminal

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, xampp

I try to create a database through terminal in a laravel project and it tells me that the database is created but when I go to phpMyAdmin I can not find it.

```
mysql> create database house
-> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does 
not exist
```

I was using MAMP and it did not work so I used Xamp and it did not work also, and when I run :

```
mysql> select user from mysql.user
-> ;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
| user             |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

it gives me another users not existed in MAMP phpMyAdmin or Xamp phpMyAdmin.

Is there a way to connect successfuly to MAMP or XAMP phpMyAdmin.

Note:

IP address for Laravel project: 127.0.0.1 the same with MAMP 
but IP address for Xamp is : 192.168.64.2

Here is my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pizzahouse
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Where do you use phpMyAdmin in this? If any user does not exist properly, why not fix that?

Comment: The problem is that mysql create these users and database somewhere else where I can not reach it through Xampp or MAMP, I can reach it only through terminal and as you see the user: mysql.infoschema exist in users table but when I try to SHOW DATABSES it tells me that the user is not exist

Comment: Then why not create this database using a proper user? I don't think you should use `mysql.infoschema` to do anything unless you are completely sure that you want to use this user

Comment: I used this : 'mysql -u root' to use root user but it still create database using 'mysql.infoschema'.. I do not know why it keeps doing that

Comment: Why not use a "proper" user instead of `root`?

Comment: I did and still receive the same error: mysql> create user ahmed
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> create database try
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

Comment: Is this a new installation or a database that's existed for some time? Do you have any data in it you wish to preserve? You should not usually run XAMPP and WAMP along side each other, since they more or less serve the same general purpose and you're at risk for them competing for the same ports and (potentially) MySQL's data directory. Do you need both? Somehow, your MySQL user permissions are damaged (mysql.infoschema is a system user for MySQL to use internally). Why it exists but can't be used internally by MySQL isn't clear, but the error message shows that this internal user is damaged.

Comment: You are right, I had to delete both Xampp and MAMP and iuninstall all mysql from my computer then I installed a fresh copy of Xampp only and I connected with database through terminal effeciently. Thank you  @Isaac Bennetch

Comment: Great, I'm glad you were able to resolve it. I'm going to rewrite a bit of that below as an answer to help anyone who has this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, your MySQL user permissions are damaged (mysql.infoschema is a system user for MySQL to use internally). Why it exists but can't be used internally by MySQL isn't clear, but the error message shows that this internal user is damaged. The easiest way to recover from this is to reinstall MySQL (through XAMPP or WAMP or whichever package you end up selecting). You'll need to make sure to remove the entire MySQL data directory (which the uninstaller should either do automatically or ask you about, I don't recall which). Note that **this will destroy any existing data in your database** so you should not proceed if you have existing data you wish to preserve.

When you reinstall, MySQL will properly configure these required system users and you should be back up and running.

You should not usually run XAMPP and WAMP along side each other, since they more or less serve the same general purpose and you're at risk for them competing for the same ports and (potentially) MySQL's data directory. That could be what happened here, although there isn't really enough information to know. MySQL uses a "data directory" (datadir) to hold on disk all the database files. It's plausible (although perhaps unlikely) that your two servers (XAMPP and WAMP) have both ended up using the same path which would cause corruption of the databases, tables, and users. Aside from that, some freak server crash, disk corruption, or incorrect SQL command could have caused the problem as well.

It *may* be possible to restore the existing system users with a command such as `mysqld --initialize --user=mysql` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html), and note that you'll need to reset the root password on next login), but with this degree of uncertainty, I think it's an all-around safer option to reinstall from scratch — again pointing out that this will destroy any data that already exists in your database.